# Pygame sprite graphics not updating

Tags: python, pygame, surface

I'm having some difficulties in a pygame project updating a sprite's appearance based on its direction of travel. Basically, I want to draw a rectangle on the bottom, top, left, or right half of a square if it's moving up, down, right, or left, respectively. While my debug print statements show correctly which way the square is moving, the pygame.draw.rect() method doesn't seem to be doing anything to the Surface (self.image) associated with the trace object.

```
import pygame

black = (  0,  0,    0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue =  (  0,   0, 255)
green = (  0, 255,   0)
red =   (255,   0,   0)

class Trace(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,startx,starty):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15,15])

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = startx
        self.rect.y = starty


    def update(self,walls):
        self.image.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, red, [self.rect.x,self.rect.y], 7)

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        diffx = pos[0] - self.rect.x
        diffy = pos[1] - self.rect.y 


        #determine primary direction
        if abs(diffx) >= abs(diffy):
            if diffx >= 0:
                print("moving right")
                pygame.draw.rect(self.image, red, [self.rect.x,self.rect.y,7,15], 7)
            else:
                print("moving left")
                pygame.draw.rect(self.image, red, [self.rect.x,self.rect.y,7,15], 7)
        else:
            if diffy >= 0 :
                print("moving down")
                pygame.draw.rect(self.image, red, [self.rect.x,self.rect.y,7,15], 7)
            else:
                print("moving up")

        #move on x axis and check for collisions
        self.rect.x += diffx/3
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for wall in collisions:
            if diffx > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right

        #move on y axis and check for collisions
        self.rect.y += diffy/3
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for wall in collisions:
            if diffy > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom




class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

pygame.init()
displaysize = [600,400]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(displaysize)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

testtrace = Trace(0,0)
tracelist = pygame.sprite.Group()
tracelist.add(testtrace)

wall = Wall(100,100,40,40,blue)
wall2 = Wall(155,100,40,40,blue)
wall3 = Wall(210,100,40,40,blue)
wall4 = Wall(100,155,40,40,blue)
wall5 = Wall(155,155,40,40,blue)
wall6 = Wall(210,155,40,40,blue)
walllist = pygame.sprite.Group()
walllist.add(wall,wall2,wall3,wall4,wall5,wall6)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #close window on quit
            done = True 

    screen.fill(white)
    tracelist.update(walllist)
    tracelist.draw(screen)
    walllist.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

I't's clear that I'm updating the position of the trace object every frame, but the image remains black with no rectangles drawn anywhere on it (I don't have them drawing to the right side of the square yet, I just want any kind of result at this point.) Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? thanks a ton!

Comment: you forgot  `draw.rect` for `"moving up"`

Answer (score 2):

You have to `draw.rect` (and `draw.circle`) on `self.image` with `[0,0,7,15]`. You can't use `rect.x`, `rect.y` because it can give you `[100,100,7,15]` and it is ouside of `self.image` area.

Coordinates for pixels on `self.image` area are always `x:0..14` `y:0..14`

-

`rect.x` `rect.y` is used by `group.draw()` to `blit` image on screen in correct place.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. This kind of oversight is exactly the reason it's so helpful to have a resource like stackoverflow. Thanks man!